# Any Circle images overlapping plugin in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, overlapping, circleimage

Is there any plugin in Flutter which could achieve something like the profile picture preview of persons who liked the picture on Instagram?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try my package ([signed_spacing_flex](https://pub.dev/packages/signed_spacing_flex)). It's exactly the same as a normal `Row` (or `Column` and `Flex`). But it also lets you set negative spacing which causes its children to overlap. You can also set which children should be on top when they overlap.

In your case it would be something like:

```dart
const imageURL = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Instagram_logo_2022.svg/150px-Instagram_logo_2022.svg.png";

SignedSpacingRow(
  spacing: -16.0,
  stackingOrder: StackingOrder.firstOnTop,
  children: const [
    CircleAvatar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      child: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 18,
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imageURL),
      ),
    ),
    CircleAvatar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      child: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 18,
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imageURL),
      ),
    ),
    CircleAvatar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      child: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 18,
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imageURL),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

It also works with expanded children if you need.

Comment: Good job buddy! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

There is no plugin but you can make a custom one using circle avatars(with white border) in a stack.

```
class CustomAvatars extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 80,
      height: 40,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 18,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                child: Image.asset('assets\image'), // Provide your custom image
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 18,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                child: Image.asset('assets\image'), // Provide your custom image
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 18,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                child: Image.asset('assets\image'), // Provide your custom image
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but the Align doesn't overlap them like in the image attached.

Comment: It does when you are using stack widget, check if you are using stack

Answer (score 6):

Or you can use Align inside of `ListView();` widget

```
Widget _stackedHeads() => Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 100,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 4,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Align(
              widthFactor: 0.6,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 18,

                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      'https://www.jessleewong.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/jessleewong_20191109_3.jpg'), // Provide your custom image
                ),
              ),
            );
          }));
```

cames in handy when your content is dynamic, in that code in `Align();` widget property `widthFactor:` determines how much in horizontal they should overlap.

Answer (score 1):

There is no plugin but you can make a custom one using circle avatars and positioned in a stack.

```
      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
      class CustomAvatar extends StatelessWidget {
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            width: 80,
            height: 40,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  left: 0,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 18,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      child: Image.asset('assets\image'), // Provide your custom image
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 8,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 18,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      child: Image.asset('assets\image'), // Provide your custom image
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 16,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 18,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      child: Image.asset('assets\image'), // Provide your custom image
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      }
```